# jQuery or JS to pre-populate and submit a text field after dynamically generated input field finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, botframework, web-chat, power-virtual-agents

My goal is to trigger a specific chat flow within the Microsoft Power Virtual Agent service based on the page the user is on. I haven't been able to find a way to customise the Microsoft service to dynamically start at a specific chat topic other than one [fixed one using these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/configure-bot-greeting).

I want to use jQuery to pre-populate the dynamically generated text field:

```
$('.webchat__send-box-text-box__input').val('red');
```

The above code works where I see the word "red" appear in the text box very briefly but then it gets overwritten by the code that is generating the input field. If I run the above script manually from the browser console after everything has loading, it works fine.

Is there a way to customise the Microsoft webchat code to get the user to the start of a specific flow, or alternatively can I automate the insertion of the right words so that the user is automatically taken to the start of the relevant chat flow? It would be great if I could set a paramter in the webchat JS code that sets a topic right from the beginning, but I haven't found any instructions that suggests this is possible-just some basic styling parameters.

This is the code from Microsoft that generates a web chat interface:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
  <script>
        const styleOptions = {
           // Add styleOptions to customize web chat canvas
           hideUploadButton: true
        };

        // Add your BOT ID below
        var BOT_ID = "[BOT ID VALUE REDACTED]";

        var theURL = "https://powerva.microsoft.com/api/botmanagement/v1/directline/directlinetoken?botId=" + BOT_ID;
        const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
           {},
           ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
               if (action.type === "DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED") {
                  dispatch({
                      meta: {
                           method: "keyboard",
                       },
                       payload: {
                           activity: {
                                 channelData: {
                                      postBack: true,
                                 },
                                  //Web Chat will show the 'Greeting' System Topic message which has a trigger-phrase 'hello'
                                  name: 'startConversation',
                                  type: "event"
                             },
                        },
                        type: "DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY",
                   });
             }
             return next(action);
          }
       );
       fetch(theURL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(conversationInfo => {
                window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                    {
                        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                            token: conversationInfo.token,
                        }),
                        store: store,
                        styleOptions: styleOptions
                    },
                    document.getElementById('webchat');
                );
            })
            .catch(err => console.error("An error occurred: " + err));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to overcome. All you need to do is decide on how you want to identify the page being visited, filter on that in Web Chat's store, and post an activity that would trigger the appropriate topic.

In the example below, my page is title "PVA Test Page". When the page loads that has that title, using the `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED` action type and matching on `document.title === 'PVA Test Page'`, then the `DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY` action is dispatched. The activity I have setup is of type 'message' and sends a text value of 'store hours'. In my PVA bot I have a topic that is setup to return dialog detailing the store hours. The trigger phrases are configured to recognize that text value. So, providing all those conditions are met, the store hours are returned as a dialog when the page loads.

Si

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>PVA Test Page</title>

  [ ... ]

</head>

[ ... ]

</html>
```

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
  {},
  ( { dispatch } ) => next => action => {
    if ( action.type === "DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED" ) {
      if (document.title === 'PVA Test Page') {
        dispatch( {
          meta: {
            method: "keyboard",
          },
          payload: {
            activity: {
              channelData: {
                postBack: true,
              },
              text: 'store hours',
              type: "message"
            },
          },
          type: "DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY",
        } );
      }
    }
    return next( action );
  }
);
```

[image]